# CoovaChilli - DHCP Server Limit Issue

Tags: coovachilli

I have a problem with CoovaChilli 1.2.5 and his parameter HS_NETMASK. 
I configure chilli network in that way:

```
HS_WANIF=eth0              # WAN Interface toward the Internet
HS_LANIF=eth1          # Subscriber Interface for client devices
HS_NETWORK=10.100.100.0    # HotSpot Network (must include HS_UAMLISTEN)
HS_NETMASK=255.255.252.0   # HotSpot Network Netmask
HS_UAMLISTEN=10.100.100.1   # HotSpot IP Address (on subscriber network)
HS_UAMPORT=3990            # HotSpot UAM Port (on subscriber network)
HS_UAMUIPORT=4990          # HotSpot UAM "UI" Port (on subscriber network, for embedded portal)
```

Unfortunately CoovaChilli continues to assign only 512, as shown using command:

```
chilli_query list | wc -l
```

When CoovaChilli starts up it takes the correnct configuration file and tun0 is running with the correct network parameters:

```
tun0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:10.100.100.1  P-t-P:10.100.100.1  Mask:255.255.252.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:18475105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24707990 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
      RX bytes:2759781458 (2.5 GiB)  TX bytes:26712874647 (24.8 GiB)
```

I don't understand why there is a limit of 512 IPs or where is the correct parameter that I have to modify to have a more wide DHCP range.
I really need to understand if is a software bug/limit or there is something wrong in the configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for following parameters in file `src/cmdline.c`:

```
--maxclients=INT  Maximum number of clclients/subscribers     
                        (default=`512')",
args_info->maxclients_arg = 512
```

From `src/chilli_limits.h`:

```
MAX_REGEX_PASS_THROUGHS 512 /* Max number of allowed UAM pass-throughs */

MAX_IPSRC_PASS_THROUGHS 512 /* Max number of allowed IP source addresses, for Layer3 */
```

Comment: Perfect, your answer was the correct solution for my problem. Thank you very much.